# How to DrawText in PDF4Net with multiple language characters?

Tags: c#, pdf, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a c# string into PDF using PDF4NET's DrawText function.  I have a string with random characters in English, Chinese, Japanese and Korean and they are in random positions within the string.  What Font should I use?  Alternatively, how can I detect and break the string into language segments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arial Unicode MS is the only font that I've seen to support all these languages, but the font is not free.

Otherwise you have to split the string into parts based on the fonts you have and the characters they support. If you use [Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) fonts (which have support for English and CJK in separate fonts) you analyze each character and if it is English it goes in one string, if it is CJK is goes in another string.

For example if you have the sample string 'EECKEJECJKEEE' (where E is English, C - Chinese, J - Japanese, K - Korean), it will be split into 7 strings: EE, CK, E, J, E, CJK, EEE. English strings will be drawn with a font, CJK strings with another font. You can measure each string you draw so you can place the following string right next to it.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm).

Comment: Any idea how to detect CJK languages?

Comment: The Unicode standard tells you which character codes belong to various languages: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_(Unicode_block)